# Cannot make non static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::getTable() static in class App\bill, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have created method in model as :

```
class bill extends Model
{
public static function getTable() {

    $tables = Bill::where('order_type', '0')
                ->where('table_no','<>','')
                ->groupBy('table_no')
                ->get();
    return $tables;
} }
```

and in controller i am accessing this method as

```
public function bill()
{
    $data = Bill::getTable();

    return view('bill.bills');
}
```

It is giving error as `Cannot make non static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::getTable() static in class App\bill` at line no 17. I am not getting what is wrong ?

Comment: You have to make the method non-static, this will allow the base Model class to be loaded. Instanciate the bill model in your controller and call it. try this and get back here if you encounter problems

Comment: I added this two lines  $bill = new Bill();

        $data = $bill->getTable(); now it is not redirecting to view, black page showing

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Bill::where('order_type', '=','0')`?

Comment: it doesnt matter.. event if i write Bill::all(); i am getting same error.

Comment: Check your logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the problem is that the Eloquent `Model` abstract class which is a parent class of your `bill` (you shouldn't break convetion and use `bill` and `Bill` in another place) has non-static method: `getTable` so you cannot override it in a static way. PLease change the name of this method.

Answer (score 0):

You may have done extends in Laravel's built-in class.
That's about it.

```
class Collection extends \App\Models\FbAccount implements ArrayAccess, CanBeEscapedWhenCastToString, Enumerable
```

Here I am inheriting from `\App\Models\FbAccount`, because of this, this error occurs. Remove inheritance.

Thank you.